# Angular Nested *ngFor is giving Infinite results on being used in a HTML Template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using Github API to built a Repositories Viewer. I'm taking repo.name as an input for another variable and passing it as a parameter to a function which indeed calls to get the Languages used as in a repository.

The problem is that it not displaying individual set of languages for a repository, it's looping them all and running infinitely.

**HTML File**

```
 <div class="user-repos">
    <ul id="repos" *ngFor="let repo of repos | paginate:{ id:'listing_repos',itemsPerPage:10, currentPage:page, totalItems:totalRecords}">
      <li>
        <h4>{{ repo.name | uppercase}}</h4>
        <p>{{ repo.description }}</p>
          <ul *ngFor="let lang of languagesUsed(repo.name)">
              <li>{{lang}}</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**Component.ts file for the same**

```
export class UserComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() username:any;
  
  constructor(private githubUser:UserDataService) { }
  repos:Array<any> = [];
  avatar:any;
  name:String = '';
  location:String = '';
  bio:String = '';
  twitter:String = ''; 
  github:String = '';
  totalRecords = 0;
  page = 1;
  langs:Array<any> = [];
  

  getUser(){
    this.githubUser.getData(this.username).subscribe((data)=>{
        //console.log(data);

        this.avatar = data.avatar_url;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.location = data.location;
        this.bio = data.bio;
        this.twitter = `https://twitter.com/${data.twitter_username}`;
        this.github = `https://github.com/${data.login}`;
    })
  }

  getRepos(){
    this.githubUser.getRepositories(this.username).subscribe((repos)=>{
        this.repos = repos;
        this.totalRecords = repos?.length;
        // this.languagesUsed = Object.keys(repos.languages_url);
    })
  }

  languagesUsed(repoName:any){
      this.githubUser.getLanguages(this.username, repoName).subscribe((languages)=>{
        // console.log(Object.keys(languages));
        this.langs = Array.from(Object.keys(languages));
      })
      return this.langs;
    }

    ngOnInit(): any{
      this.getUser();
      this.getRepos();
    }

  }
```

**Service.ts for fetching the API's**

```
export class UserDataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  getData(username:String):Observable<any>{

    let user = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
    return this.http.get(user);
  }

  getRepositories(username:String):Observable<any>{
    let repos = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`;
    return this.http.get(repos);
  }

  getLanguages(username:String, repo:String):Observable<any>{
    let languages = `https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repo}/languages`;
    return this.http.get(languages);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us a code here? It is just unclear, to think about it in a theoretical perspective

Comment: @PankajParkar I have added the code, please have a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused because of `languagesUsed` function, couple of problems with it

1. Used as a binding `languagesUsed()`
2. Due to the `async` call, returned value `this.langs` won't be the right value.
3. On each iteration, it will make an ajax call. This is causing an infinite loop

To fix this, you move the fetch languages logic as a serial operation (`switchMap`) on the observable level. As soon as you received a specific `repo`, make another call to bring the `languages` for that `user`. Thereafter extend the repo object with the `languages` array received.

Something like below

```
// after receiving the repos, 
const allRepoWithLanguages = repos.map(repo => 
  // loop over them and make a `getLanguages` ajax call
  this.githubUser.getLanguages(this.username, repo.name)
  .pipe(
     // extend repo with languages
     map(languages => ({...repo, languages }))
  )
);
```

Let's extend the logic just we've seen into actual implementation.

**TS**

```
getRepos(){
    this.githubUser.getRepositories(this.username).pipe(
      switchMap(repos => {
         const allRepoWithLanguages = repos.map(repo => 
            this.githubUser.getLanguages(this.username, repo.name)
            .pipe(
               // amending repo with languages
               map(languages => ({...repo, languages }))
            )
         );
         return forkJoin(allRepoWithLanguages);
      }),
    ).subscribe((repos)=>{
        this.repos = repos;
        this.totalRecords = repos?.length;
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-repos">
   <ul id="repos" *ngFor="let repo of repos | paginate:{ id:'listing_repos',itemsPerPage:10, currentPage:page, totalItems:totalRecords}">
      <li>
        <h4>{{ repo.name | uppercase}}</h4>
        <p>{{ repo.description }}</p>
          <ul *ngFor="let lang of repo.languages">
              <li>{{lang}}</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```